# FPDF Format specific parts of the row

Tags: php, fpdf

I'm using fpdf to make up a pdf file and have things such as:

```
 $pdf->SetWidths(array(110, 110));
$data = array(
    "Home Telephone Number: $homeNumber",
    "Mobile Telephone Number: $mobileNumber"
);

$pdf->CustomRow($data);
```

Now what I would like to do is see if there is a way to modify the text in $data so that Home Telephone Number: and Mobile Telephone Number: are bold but not the text stored in $homeNumber and $mobileNumber. Is there any way of doing this?

edit:

I am not using a new method I have created called CustomRow which is defined as so:

```
function CustomRow($data)
{
    $this->SetFont('Arial', '', 12);
    
    // Calculate the height of the row
    $nb = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++) {
        $nb = max($nb, $this->NbLines($this->widths[$i], $data[$i]));
    }
    $h = 5 * $nb;

    // Issue a page break first if needed
    $this->CheckPageBreak($h);

    $xStart = $this->GetX(); // Initial X position

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++) {
        $w = $this->widths[$i];
        $a = isset($this->aligns[$i]) ? $this->aligns[$i] : 'L';

        // Save the current position
        $x = $this->GetX();
        $y = $this->GetY();
        
        $this->Rect($x,$y,$w,$h);


        // Check if the text should be formatted as bold
        if (strpos($data[$i], ':') !== false) {
            $colonPosition = strpos($data[$i], ':');
            $textBeforeColon = substr($data[$i], 0, $colonPosition + 1); // Include the colon
            $textAfterColon = substr($data[$i], $colonPosition + 1);
            

            // Output the text before the colon in bold
            $this->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 12);
            $this->MultiCell($w, 5, $textBeforeColon, 0, $a);

            // Reset the font style to regular
            $this->SetFont('Arial', '', 12);

            // Output the text after the colon in regular style
            $this->MultiCell($w, 5, $textAfterColon, 0, $a);
        } else {
            // No colon found, so display the text as is in regular style
            $this->MultiCell($w, 5, $data[$i], 0, $a);
        }

        // Move to the right of the cell
        $this->SetXY($x + $w, $y);
    }

    // Go to the next line
    $this->Ln($h);

    // Reset the X position to the start of the row
    $this->SetX($xStart);
}
```

This does kinda work, except the text after the colon goes onto a new cell, so just wondering how could I fix this so that they're both on the same cell?

Comment: We don't know what `SetWidths()` and `Row()` do. They are not [part of FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/index.php). Perhaps you need to add some more code to show us? In FPDF the font style is changed with [SetFont()](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/setfont.htm).